# R: Arguments imply differing number of rows using financial data

Tags: r

I am intending to build a code to check the cointegration of two time series of financial price data in order to make better forecasting of one of them.

For this purpose, I chose this two time series: BBVA historical price and IBEX35 and build this little code:

```
ibex <- new.env()
bbva <- new.env()

library(quantmod)

getSymbols("^IBEX", env = ibex, src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("2010-01-04"), to = as.Date("2015-11-30"))
getSymbols("bbva", env = bbva, src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("2010-01-04"), to = as.Date("2015-11-30"))
ibex <- ibex$IBEX
ibex <- ibex$IBEX.Adjusted
bbva <- bbva$BBVA
bbva <- bbva$BBVA.Adjusted

ldbbva <- diff(log(bbva))
ldibex <- diff(log(ibex))

mean <- mean(ldbbva, na.rm = TRUE) 
ldbbva[is.na(ldbbva)] <- mean

mean <- mean(ldibex, na.rm = TRUE) 
ldbbva[is.na(ldibex)] <- mean

library(urca)

jotest=ca.jo(data.frame(ldbbva,ldibex), type="trace", K=2, ecdet="none", spec="longrun")
```

At that point when I try to make a data frame from my time series, I face this error *arguments imply differing number of rows: 1488, 1514*.

What can I do?

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: You probably need to understand *why* these two columns are of different lengths. My guess (an this is only a guess) is that `^IBEX` is smaller because the Spanish Continuous Market is closed more often than some other markets and you lack data from days in which it is closed. If this is the issue, you might need to expand it with `NA` in the appropriate days. In any event -- look at the data itself and see where a discrepancy first arises. Can you understand that discrepency?

Comment: You should really name things and choose what `ibex` and `bbva` should be, either `environments` or  `vectors`, you're using them as both and so probably overwriting values. (the two lines starting with `ibex <-` just overwrite the ibex variable in global environment). Try using `ibexenv` and `ibexvec` to be clear about what is what. (Then for the error message, just build the `data.frame` out of the `ca.jo`, you may get better why it fails.

Comment: The error message is not unclear. What is unclear is what I can do about it,  @Roland.

I understand your answer, @JohnColeman, but I don't know how to do it in R. The discrepancy is, indeed, what you said, but I don't know how to fill those gaps with NA.

Thanks for your advice, @Tensibai. You are completely right about environments and vectors, now I have my code more clear. In the other hand, I already had built the `data frame` out of the `ca.jo` obtaining exactly the same mistake. I guessed that talking directly about my intentions could make the questions more easy to unerstand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the time series to have them properly aligned.

```
dat <- merge(ibex, bbva)

dat <- diff(log(dat))

#mean imputation
dat <- na.aggregate(dat)

library(urca)
jotest=ca.jo(dat, type="trace", K=2, ecdet="none", spec="longrun")
###################################################### 
## Johansen-Procedure Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
###################################################### 
#
#The value of the test statistic is: 619.1603 1473.644
```